# why linux bridge learns source mac from lldp packets

Tags: linux-kernel, bridge

when an LLDP packet is received, linux bridge adds the source mac to FDB.

In function br_handle_frame(),

```
    case 0x0E:  /* 802.1AB LLDP */
        fwd_mask |= p->br->group_fwd_mask;
        if (fwd_mask & (1u << dest[5]))
            goto forward;
        *pskb = skb;
        __br_handle_local_finish(skb);
        return RX_HANDLER_PASS;
```

__br_handle_local_finish() updates FDB with the packet's source mac.

My question is: is it required by any protocol or other components to have this mac in FDB? Why is it being added?

Comment: the default for most of those received link local ether is to learn as usual (a few lines later: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.1/source/net/bridge/br_input.c#L334)